# Accessing outer variable

Tags: javascript, scope

```
Object({
  a: "string",
  b: function() { return a; }
}).b()
```

throws `a is not defined`. Is it possible to access `a` from inside `b`?

Answer (score 6):

Use `this` to properly refer the scope

```
Object({
  a: "string",
  b: function() { return this.a; }
}).b(); // return "string"
```

See [The this keyword on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for further reading.